# Use member in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hi everyone I am new with rails 3,I have a app where I want to associate a idea with a comment.

When I show an idea, in the bottom of the view I show a form to put new comment for this idea, and when a click to save a comment, I have to pass the idea_id, I create my model commment

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :idea
  attr_accessible :description, :likes, :name, :user_id, :idea_id
```

in the view of show idea a put this

```
= render :partial => "comments/index", :collection => @idea.comments
= render :partial => "comments/form",  :locals => {:comment=> @comment}
```

in the _form of the comment I include idea to obtain idea_id to save

```
= form_for [@idea, @comment] do |f|
```

and in my router I put this

```
  resources :ideas do
    member do
      resources :comments
    end
  end
```

and now I obtain this error

```
undefined method `idea_comments_path'
```

any idea, anyone knows a document to explain better how to use member in rails!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `member` for nested resources:

```
  resources :ideas do
    resources :comments
  end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html